# Trying to COUNTIFS date = this week (sunday-saturday)?

Tags: google-sheets, count, countif

I'm building a spreadsheet that automatically gets a row added when I get an application on my form. [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mYf1YX3pd8KwKXOBmESHA9gHLVrFGXUU_7E6yu96HV0/edit#gid=517358515) is the link to the sheet. As you can see, the first tab is just a list of applications, with the location they've applied for, and the date. The second tab is a daily count for each location, which is eventually sent out as an email each night. I'd like to include weekly numbers, and maybe even an ongoing weekly comparison. e.g. # of apps today, this week (so far), last week, etc.

I'm no expert with this stuff and it's getting a bit over my head possibly. Any ideas on how to get this done smoothly?? Thanks a ton in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem (like many) is primarily a problem with the organization of your raw data.

On a new tab called MK.Help, I've put the following formula in cell A2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(Applications!A2:A&"|"&Applications!S2:S&"|"&FLOOR(Applications!S2:S-2,7)+2&"|"&Applications!B2:R),"|",0,0),"where Col4 is not null and Col2>="&I2))
```

Then I made a simple table on the right with some fairly straightforward COUNTIFS() that look like this:

```
=COUNTIFS($C:$C,H$2,$D:$D,$F3)
```

The layout of the data *vertically* is what's making the formulas relatively simple for the summary.

Comment: I see, interesting. The raw data is automatically added through Zapier though. I think I'm going to have to make it work based on that data layout.

Comment: @ChristianGillum it's not clear if you noticed that the vertical layout i built is being generated DYNAMICALLY from your zapier output.